# SICP Exercise 2.5 - How to represent negative numbers?

Tags: scheme, lisp, sicp, data-representation

I'm currently reading the SICP, and working on Exercise 2.5 :

> Exercise 2.5. Show that we can represent pairs of nonnegative integers using only numbers and arithmetic operations if we represent the pair *a* and *b* as the integer that is the product ***2**<sup>a</sup>**3**<sup>b</sup>*. Give the corresponding definitions of the procedures `cons`, `car`, and `cdr`.

And I've found [a code](https://codology.net/post/sicp-solution-exercise-2-5/):

```
(define (my-cons a b)
  (* (expt 2 a) (expt 3 b)))

(define (my-car x)
  (define (car-iter x count)
    (if (= 0 (remainder x 2))
        (car-iter (/ x 2) (+ 1 count))
        count))
  (car-iter x 0))

(define (my-cdr x)
  (define (cdr-iter x count)
    (if (= 0 (remainder x 3))
        (cdr-iter (/ x 3) (+ 1 count))
        count))
  (cdr-iter x 0))
```

My question is : ***What if the requirement of "Nonnegative integers" needs to be changed to "Accept both negative and nonnegative integers"*** ?

Example :

```
> (define x (my-cons 2 -5))
> (my-car x)
2
> (my-cdr x)
-5
```

How to modify the code? I can't figure it out.

Thank you. May you have a great day.

Comment: This is a math problem, really, not a programming question. You obviously cannot represent negative numbers as 2^n*3^m, so you will have to choose some alternative representation. One obvious solution would be to include an extra bit/boolean representing "is negative".

Comment: Another solution along the same lines as this would be to include powers of five and seven, and use two numbers for the signs and two for the magnitudes.

Answer (score 2):

As amalloy said in a comment this is really a maths problem.  This encoding works because of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, which is that any positive natural number has a unique prime factorisation: every positive natural can be represented uniquely as the product of a number of primes raised to powers, where in particular 1 is the product of *no* primes.

So you could encode the sign of the integers using one or more additional prime factors (you only need one, in fact, as you can for instance write the thing as 2^a3^b5^s where s is an integer in [0,3] which encodes the signs of both elements).

An alternative way is simply to use the existing representation but to map the integers to the naturals.  This is nice because it's a practical demonstration that there are no more integers than naturals.  Such a map might be:

- if i >= 0 then 2i.
- otherswise -2i - 1.

It's easy to see that this is a [*one-to-one*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) correspondence, and also that 0 maps to 0 (which makes 0 a nice value for `nil`).

Here are these maps, written (sorry) in typed Racket as I'm trying to work out if I can use it.

```
(define (Z->N (i : Integer)) : Natural
  ;; map an integer to a natural
  (if (>= i 0)
      (* i 2)
      (- (* (- i) 2) 1)))

(define (N->Z (n : Natural)) : Integer
  ;; map the naturals into the integers
  (let-values ([(q r) (quotient/remainder n 2)])
    (if (zero? r)
        q
        (- (- q) 1))))
```

Now there is another problem with the implementation you have: it will happily handle numbers which are not of the form 2^a3^b, for instance anything which has other prime factors.  The way to deal with that is to check that numbers are of that form when extracting the powers: in practice this means checking the number is of the form 2^a*3^b*1.

So the code below does this, as well as encoding integers as above.  This again is in typed Racket (sorry, again), and it also makes use of multiple values and probably some other things which only exist in Racket.

```
(define (defactor (n : Natural) (p : Natural)) : (Values Natural Natural)
  ;; Given n and a factor p, return m where p does not divide m,
  ;; and j, the number of factors of p removed (so n = m*p^j)
  (let df-loop ([m : Natural n]
                [j : Natural 0])
    (let-values ([(q r) (quotient/remainder m p)])
      (if (zero? r)
          (df-loop q (+ j 1))
          (values m j)))))
  
(define (kar&kdr (k : Positive-Integer)) : (Values Integer Integer)
  ;; Given something which should be a kons, return its kar & kdr.
  ;; If it is not a kons signal an error
  (let*-values ([(k2 encoded-kar) (defactor k 2)]
                [(k23 encoded-kdr) (defactor k2 3)])
    (unless (= k23 1)
      (error 'kar&kdr "not a cons"))
    (values (N->Z encoded-kar) (N->Z encoded-kdr))))

(define (kons (the-kar : Integer) (the-kdr : Integer)) : Positive-Integer
  (* (expt 2 (Z->N the-kar))
     (expt 3 (Z->N the-kdr))))

(define (kar (the-kons : Positive-Integer)) : Integer
  (let-values ([(the-kar the-kdr) (kar&kdr the-kons)])
    the-kar))

(define (kdr (the-kons : Positive-Integer)) : Integer
  (let-values ([(the-kar the-kdr) (kar&kdr the-kons)])
    the-kdr))
```

We can go a little further and define a representation of the empty list, which will be `0` and a way of making lists:

```
;;; since 2^a3^b is never zero, 0 is a good candidate for the empty
;;; list: 'kill' is a pun on 'nil'.
;;;

(define kill : Zero 0)

;;; And now we can write some predicates and a version of list.
;;; (kist 1 2 3) takes a very, very long time.
;;;

(define (kill? (x : Natural)) : Boolean
  (zero? x))

(define (kons? (x : Natural)) : Boolean
  (not (kill? x)))
               
(define (kist . (l : Integer *)) : Natural
  (let kist/spread ((lt l))
    (if (null? lt)
        kill
        (kons (first lt) (kist/spread (rest lt))))))
```

And now

```
> (define d (kons 123 -456))
> d
- : Integer [more precisely: Nonnegative-Integer]
51385665200410193914365219310409629004573395973849642473134969706165383608831740620563388986738635202925909198851954060195023302783671526117732269828652603388431987979605951272414330987611274752111186624164906143978901704325355283206259678088536996807776750955110998323447711166379786727609752016045005681785186498933895920793982869940159108073471074955985333560653268614500306816876936016985137986665262182684386364851688838680773491949813254691225004097103180392486216812280763694296818736638062547181764608
> (kar d)
- : Integer
123
> (kdr d)
- : Integer
-456
> (kdr (+ d 1))
kar&kdr: not a cons [,bt for context]
```

If you try to compute, say `(kist 1 2 3)` it will take a very, very long time.

Comment: 0 has no prime factorization though.

Comment: Also, we only encode pairs of integers, so there's no place for `cons` here really, since we don't have pairs of nums and lons (lists of nums), only of nums and nums. A natural encoding for lons seems to be to just use ith prime's exponent for the ith num in a lon (1-based). An empty list would then be represented by 1. :) interesting property of this repr is O(1) access to each index. But cons would be O(n)... unless we use another int to hold the "negative" indices!

Comment: @WillNess: yes, it doesn't, I will change that.  But you can still represent any pair of non-negative numbers (a, b) as 2^a3^b so this doesnt matter.  It's trivial to extend things by representing the empty list as `0` as I suggested.  I'll do that (and also fix some of the types which were wrong).

Comment: So then, `klist 1 2 3 = kons 1 (kons 2 (kons 3 0)) = 2^2 * 3^( 2^4 * 3^( 2^6 * 3^0 )) = 4 * 3^( 16 * 3^64 ) >=~ 10^(10^30)`, shall we say, if I'm not mistaken. Encoding it as `2^2*3^4*5^6 = 5062500` looks a bit more feasible. :) :)

Comment: @WillNess: yes, I was extending the SICP encoding, not inventing a new one.

Comment: using more prime bases is also extending, just in another direction, I think. All equally valid, correctness-wise.

Comment: I'd even consider your change more radical. I just deal with the numbers, you *reinterpret* an encoded pair as a plain number, bridging the gap between separate types, a feat I initially thought impossible to achieve. :)

Comment: @WillNess Um, the *only* thing I did was map the integers onto the naturals and point out that 1 is a reasonable choice for the empty list.  Everything else is in SICP.  Never mind, I'm not going to argue with you about this as it's a waste of both of our time.